# Difference between nchar and object.size in R

Tags: r, object, size, nchar

What is the difference between nchar and object.size?

```
Sample below: 
nchar("TestData", type="bytes")
8
format(object.size("TestData"), units = "b")
"104 bytes"
```

Comment: Related: [Understanding object.size() versus nchar()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394444/understanding-object-size-versus-nchar); "_object size doesn't tell you how many bytes the data is actually taking up, it just tells you how many bytes have been set aside_"

Comment: See also [hadley on object size](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#object-size)

Comment: Thanks Henrik. Is there a way in R to limit the byte size of an object? i.e. if the object.size is currently 216, i want to create a value with only 64 bytes.

Comment: It's unfortunately not entirely clear to me what you mean. Maybe post a new question on this topic, where you can provide a more thorough explanation with a small example. Cheers.